# Как добавить заголовок запроса к vlc плееру на андроид?

Tags: c#, http, vlc

Я использую это:

```cs
mediaPlayer.Media = new Media(libVLC, URL, FromType.FromLocation);
```

Но это не работает, так как заголовок Referer не совпадает с url сайта, возникает ошибка 403 Forbidden.

Comment: вот только пост код 403 значит нехватку прав, а не неправильный урл

Comment: Плкажите весь метод, не экономьте на буквах.

Comment: @finally я и не говорил про неправильный url, я говорю о том, что сайт блокирует запросы с других ресурсов, а чтобы притвориться "своим" необходима возможность отредактировать headers запроса, чтобы он был точно таким же как и запросы, которые составляет сайт

Comment: @aepot  `Media media = new Media(libVLC, Url, FromType.FromLocation);                          
MediaConfiguration mc = new MediaConfiguration();                         
media.AddOption(mc);
 media.AddOption(":input-fast-seek");
media.AddOption(":preferred-resolution=-1");
mediaPlayer.Media = media;
media.Dispose();
VideoView1.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer.Play();`